# passing variables from a javascript file to another html page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a variable value in one javascript file. How do I access this variable in another html page, value when a user clicks that particular html link. I have tried to use the concept of  set and get cookies based on the variable, so that I can access this variable in another html page. Is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: use `localStorage` for this purpose.

Comment: `localStorage` is only for HTML5 browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Use sessionStorage!

In the first page, initiate the value inside sessionStorage, for example I'm passing a userID value 24. Here's how you set it;

```
sessionStorage.userID = 24
```

Then, here's how to access it anywhere else;

```
console.log(sessionStorage.userID) // = 24
```

On logout, remember to clear it!

```
sessionStorage.clear()
```

Comment: Why do I have to use .clear() function. Shoudnt, the session be cleared out once i close the browser.

Comment: There will be users who don't simply close the browser. Just a precaution. Anyway, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also adapt the link to encode the information. Change the href with javascript.

Either add a query string:
    
Or add a hash:

Second one might be safer as it doesn't depend on how your server handles queries, it should preserve the hash.

Once on the new page use javascript again to get the info back from the current url using `window.location`